# PHP AES 128 bit encryption/decryption

Tags: php, encryption, aes-gcm

I'm trying to understand how to AES encrypt a piece of text(16 bytes - 128 bits). This code is from [php manual](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.openssl-encrypt.php):

```
$key = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32);
$plaintext = "message to be encrypted";
$cipher = "aes-128-gcm";
if (in_array($cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods()))
{
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
    $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv, $tag);
    //store $cipher, $iv, and $tag for decryption later
    $original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv, $tag);
    echo $original_plaintext."\n";
}
```

The only problem with this is that i don't really understand it. `$cipher` is `aes-128-gcm` but i'm getting a 32 bytes encryption.

So my questions are:
Can somebody help me understand how it actually works?

Is it possible to make it 16 bytes/128 bites?

And is it safe to store `$cipher`, `$iv`, `$key` and `$tag` into a MySQL database for later use?

P.S: if i change `$key` length to `16` instead of `32` the final output of `$ciphertext` is still 32 bytes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> The only problem with this is that i don't really understand it. $cipher is aes-128-gcm but i'm getting a 32 bytes encryption.

AES-GCM is an authenticated cipher. If you're trying to learn how the basic building block works, you want to play with `aes-128-ecb` instead.

If you want a real-world encryption mode, you want to keep using GCM, [never ECB](https://blog.filippo.io/the-ecb-penguin).

> And is it safe to store $cipher, $iv, $key and $tag into a MySQL database for later use?

You can store everything *except* the key, safely. The key lets you decrypt.